# Select start of text node in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selection, range

I have an editable iframe with some textnodes. During editing i want (on some condition) set the cursor to the start of a text node. In FireFox this works fine using the following code. In Chrome instead the cursor is set to the end of the previous sibling (also text node). I am using this code:

```
/* get selection */
var selection = this.iframewin.getSelection();

/* create new range */
var newrange = this.iframedoc.createRange();
newrange.setStart(textnode, 0);
newrange.setEnd(textnode, 0);

/* set new range */
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(newrange);
```

As far as i know both FireFox and Chrome do fully comply with the DOM Range spec. So shouldn't they handle this code equally? Or am i doing something else wrong? If you need any further information please ask.

Edit:
Just after posting i found the bug report that describes this for Chrome:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23189

So i think Chrome users have to deal with that.

Comment: Yes, it's an annoying bug with no sign of anyone fixing it. You could post your edit as an answer and accept it, to help anyone else coming to this page in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after posting i found the bug report that describes this for Chrome:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23189

So i think Chrome users have to deal with that.